# SDK Rich Presence Discrod С# | Can't figure out how to create rich presence via SDK Discord

Tags: c#, discord, sdk

I am trying to install the Discord SDK for my C # console project for the sake of a test, but I am failing.

I have very little interaction with Visual Studio, with which I write the code, so please help with installing the SDK. I try to do everything according to what was said below, but perhaps I do not fully understand the sequence:

> 1. Open up that SDK zip that you downloaded.
> 2. Create a folder in your project directory called DiscordGameSDK and
>    copy the contents of the csharp/ folder to it
> 3. Build your solution then place the .dll in the directory of the .exe
>    (either x86 or x86_64 version depending on your compile platform).
>    If you compile for Any CPU you may need to perform additional
>    wrapping around DLL importing (like setting the DLL directory
>    dynamically) to make sure you load the correct DLL.

https://discord.com/developers/docs/game-sdk/sdk-starter-guide

I don't quite understand the third line of actions related to the solution, dll and exe files

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: I tried, ran the code from the example, but the console gives an error:

  System.BadImageFormatException HRESULT: 0x8007000B

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm writing in VS Code, I created a Discord Game SDK folder in my console project and moved all the files from the csharp folder to the DiscordGameSDK folder. After that, I compiled the project and transferred all the files from the lib folder to the bin/Debug/net6.0 folder

Visual Studio should work the same way. (Not sure)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du4tk.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).